# How to search for a string including spaces in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, string, character-encoding, nsstring, scanf

I have a real basic command-line program, in Objective-C, that searches for user inputed information. Unfourtunately, the code will only read the first word in series of words that the user enters. For example, if the user enters in *"Apples are great"*, only *"Apples"* is kept (and hence searched later on), excluding the *"are great"* part of the sentence.

Here's what I have so far:

```
char enteredQuery [128]; // array 'name' to hold the scanf string
NSString *searchQuery; // ending NSString to hold and compare the user inputed data

NSLog(@"Enter search query:");
scanf("%s", enteredQuery); //will read the next line

searchQuery = [NSString stringWithCString: enteredQuery encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]; //converts scanf data into a NSString type
```

I know it's got to do with me using scanf or the character-encoder conversion, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help in solving the problem is very appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` reads a single word for the pattern `"%s"`. You may use it in a loop. May be better to use `fgets` to read from stdin. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360183/fgets-from-stdin-problems-) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555108/multiple-word-string-input-through-scanf).